# Which is more wet: ‘moist’ or ‘damp’?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, synonyms

Which contains more liquid, something that is *moist* or something that is *damp*?

Context of question:
This question was asked to a young friend of mine in her high school freshman English class. It was a bonus question on a test she was taking. My thoughts after looking at the definitions in my copy of Merriam Webster's was that both were perfect synonyms and that neither truly quantified the amount of liquid within an item.

As I thought on it a little more, I figured this would be a good question to ask on this site to see what those with more knowledge of the language would come up with.

Comment: Hi and welcome. What does the dictionary say? To include the definitions (and their ambiguity) are more conducive to helpful answers (like, "Neither." than asking the question without context. (Just fyi, this question can be closed for lack of research.)

Comment: One or the other, or maybe both.

Comment: Why do you think one is wetter than the other?

Comment: @tchrist - Because the world is black and white, and language follows mathematical precision, of course. You surprise me.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-normal-for-your-vagina-to-be-moist-or-wet-all-the-time

Comment: I think that damp = 2(moist*pi*10^-23)/e

Comment: @GeorgePompidou 10^-23 amounts to almost zero! So your saying that moist is much wetter, aren't you?! ;)

Comment: @medica, I added a little more context to the question for you. I found this very interesting that it was being asked in a high school English class yet I could not come up with a good answer to the question. That is why I thought it would be good for this site.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou - Doesn't Avogadro's number factor in there somewhere?

Comment: My feeling is that "damp" refers to water absorbed by some stuff and that "moist" relates more to seeping water, i.e. in-depth(damp) vs superficial(moist).

Comment: @LWhitson2 - A lot better, thanks! It is refreshing that you are open to the possibility that there are perfect synonyms (I'm not being sarcastic; it just is refreshing.)

Comment: That it was a "bonus question" on a "high school freshman English class" leads me to suspect that the teacher did not expect a single canonical answer, but was far more interested in the students' ability to clearly articulate their arguments.  FWIW, I once had "How many snow spheres are required to make a snowman?" as an extra-credit question on a geometry test.  Simply answering "three" got minimal points; answering "None.  In this part of the country snowmen are made of plastic" got more points.

Comment: Making a snowman would likely be difficult, if not impossible, with snow spheres. Oblate snow spheroids would be much more conducive.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

[**damp**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/damp_1):
slightly wet, often in an unpleasant way:

[**moist**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/moist):
slightly wet, especially in a way that is pleasant or suitable

The same soil would be moist and damp at the same time: moist for planting seeds, and damp for sitting on.

This is the *Word Choice* note given by Longman Dictionary:

> WORD CHOICE:
>
> damp, moist, humid
>
> Use damp especially to say that something is slightly wet in an unpleasant way:
>   • The room was cold and damp.
>
> Use moist to say that something is slightly wet in a pleasant way or in the way it should be:
>   • She took a mouthful of the delicious moist cake.
>   • rich, moist soil
>
> Use humid to talk about the weather or the air when it is slightly wet and makes you feel uncomfortable:
>   • the hot humid atmosphere of a greenhouse

**Source: [Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/moist)**

Comment: Also use "moist" when you really want to annoy the seemingly large number of people who have a serious issue with the word.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist this, I was actually taken aback when I saw "moist" and "pleasant" in the same sentence.

Comment: May those who have a problem with the word "moist" be cursed never to enjoy anything moist.

Comment: @R that is a curse moist vile.

Comment: I agree with this answer – who would want to eat a damp cake? –  and would add/suggest that "moist" is more likely to be associated with warmth, and "damp" with cold. And though there seems to be some dispute as to whether, quantity-of-water-wise, there's any difference between the two words, in my "damp cake" example, I think the cake could be on the verge of soggy.

Comment: Why can I say "my hair is damp", but not "my hair is moist"? I don't think *damp* is used only to imply unpleasantness: "damp hair", "damp clothes", "damp shoes" etc. tell me that these things have been effected *externally*, i.e. soaked from the *outside*. A moist cake has absorbed liquid and has not been over baked. Frogs have *moist* or *clammy skins*, rarely *damp skins*, their thin skins absorb water internally.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's an interesting point. I think it warrants an answer. I also think I can find counter examples (with the possible exception of _hair_ all the _damp_ examples you gave carry a connotation of unpleasantness; even _damp hair_ makes me think of leaving the house with wet hair as opposed to just having stepped out of the shower) but you raise a good point with internal vs external soaking.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist i think the word "moisten" is even more hated than plain "moist"

Comment: As alluded to by Faerd, collocations by  using the COCA (American) can show many connotations. By inspecting the highest 100 frequency for both 'moist' and 'damp', the first difference is that 'moist' is used with foods and 'damp' not: moist cake, meat, chicken, crumbs, brisket, chocolate... For damp, it seems cloth and surfaces are common (and not so with moist): clothes, ground, soil, grass, hair, leaves, shirt, stone, wood.

Comment: There is surely a lot of overlap with other words: air, towel, skin, heat, wet. Unfortunately no evidence about which one is more pleasant (though I suppose food is more likable).  As to wetness, I don't find any clear connotation from the pairs beyond the moist things seem wet of themselves and damp became that way from external forces. My personal feeling is that moist is wetter than damp.

Answer (score 20):

As a counterpoint to the definitions that appear in Fard's answer (by way of *Longman's Dictionary*, I offer these definitions from *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **damp** *adj.* {ME, black damp, fr. MD or MLG, vapor; akin to OHG *damph* vapor} (1590) **1 a** *archaic* **:** being confused, bewildered, or shocked : STUPEFIED **b :** DEPRESSED, DULL **2 :** slightly or moderately wet : MOIST {a *damp* towel} also : HUMID {*damp* weather}
>
> ...
>
> **moist** *adj.* {ME *moiste*, fr. AF, perh. fr. VL *muscidus*, alter. of L mucidus slimy, fr. *mucus* nasal mucus} (14c) **1 :** slightly or moderately wet : DAMP **2 :** TEARFUL **3 :** characterized by high humidity

The *Eleventh Collegiate* also includes this usage note under the entry for *wet*:

> DAMP implies a slight or moderate absorption and often connotes an unpleasant degree of moisture {clothes will mildew if stored in a *damp* place}. ... MOIST applies to what is slightly damp or not felt as dry {treat the injury with *moist* heat}.

So the main entries for the two words give the relevant definition of *damp* as "slightly or moderately wet : MOIST" and the relevant definition of *moist* as "slightly or moderately wet : DAMP." Those are about as close to interchangeable definitions as you can find in Merriam-Webster. The usage note comparing the two words does note that some senses of *damp* involve unpleasant or uncomfortable settings, but it doesn't draw a sharp, categorical contrast between unpleasant wet (*damp*) and pleasant or suitable wet (*moist*).

In U.S. usage a damp towel is neither more nor less pleasant than a moist towel—and many other instances exist where *damp* and *moist* might be used interchangeably without significantly different connotations. UK usage may be different, but for the United States I don't think that a definite difference in wetness is implicitly understood as between *damp* and *moist*.

Comment: This distinction corresponds to my own intuition as a native English speaker and translator. Damp sounds more like a more pervasive, deep-seated moisture.

Comment: I carried out searches in COCA for _damp_ and _moist_ , comparing about 50 sentences and their contexts. If it wasn't off topic and I wasn't so lazy, I would add the (lengthy) result to my answer. I must admit that _damp_ is not condemned to have an unpleasant connotation, and was used in a fair number of the sentences just to mean "somewhat wet". But overall, there was a fair amount of evidence in support of Longman's theory. I invite you to do the same and inform me if I'm wrong. P.S. This is a half-joke, but for one thing you don't use _dampener_ to treat your skin; you use _moisturizer_.

Comment: I don't know which answer I like better, yours or the one by @Fard. Both are great answers and much better than what I could come up with.

Comment: @Fard: Moreover, you don't (in U.S. usage) compliment a baker for having produced a "damp" cake; but thanks to years of Duncan-Hines cake mix ads, you might be tempted to praise him or her for having produced a "moist cake." There certainly are areas of non-overlap (such as that one) in usage between the two adjectives. My answer cites Merriam-Webster's definitions primarily to dispute the inference a reader might draw from the Longman's definitions that a categorical black-and-white difference along the lines of "damp bad; moist good" is widely enforced in U.S. usage. ...

Comment: ... Likewise, _wet_ can have negative connotations in certain settings (as in "wet blanket," "wet noodle," "smells like a wet dog in here"), but that doesn't translate into a generally negative sense of the word _wet_ itself. I think that _damp_ has a similar profile of mostly neutral contextual meaning.

Comment: Longman says "damp" is _often_ used in an unpleasant way (much like M-W's usage note cited in your answer), and "moist" is used _especially_ for pleasant or suitable situations, so It's _not_ a black-and-white categorization. You see, it's a matter of corpus-based statistics: _wet_ is neutral because people use it equally for good and bad cases, while _damp_ and _moist_ are (generally) likelier to be used in pleasant and unpleasant situations respectively. Neither one has an inherent bias toward good or bad.

Comment: Note the etymologies. This is one of English's many, many pairs of Germanic and Latinic words with the same root meaning (holy/sacred, wood/forest, swine/pork, etc).  Which doesn't mean there can't be a meaning difference in the modern language, but it does mean any such difference is fairly recent and (usually) quite small.  The word pairs for animals, where one has come to refer exclusively to the live animal and its partner to the animal's meat prepared for eating, are the biggest such difference I can think of.

Comment: I might as well add this tiny reflection of mine: Why can I say "my hair is damp", but not "my hair is moist"? I don't think *damp* is used only to imply unpleasantness: "damp hair", "damp clothes", "damp shoes" etc. tell me that these things have been effected *externally*, i.e. soaked from the *outside*. A moist cake has absorbed liquid and has not been over-baked. Frogs have *moist* or *clammy skins*, rarely *damp skins*, their thin skins absorb water internally.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your association appears to be based on your own observations of human biology (the only biology you've likely experienced your entire life). External wetness usually causes unpleasantness in humans after an extended time, while things that we perceive as moist are those we take pleasure in. We like having a moist mouth/tongue, but we prefer to not have damp hair, clothing, or shoes; extended exposure to dampness causes your skin to wrinkle and turn whiter, and feels unpleasant, while a dry mouth is unpleasant and unhealthy.

Comment: @Færd You really should add your COCA data to your answer. It would allow us to check if Longman really does give the right idea.

Answer (score 12):

The [*OED Online*](http://oed.com/), in an entry for 'moist' updated for the third edition, September 2002, addresses the issue directly, if somewhat hesitantly:

> A. *adj.* 1. a. Slightly wet, imbued with moisture; containing liquid in a state of suspension or absorption; not dry; damp, humid.
>
> In many contexts now **differing from *damp*** by having a neutral (sometimes, esp. with reference to the texture of food, good) rather than a negative sense, and **in connoting a lesser degree of wetness**. In early use the word had a wider application.

(Bold emphasis mine.)

The note concerning the greater degree of wetness connoted ("in many contexts") by 'moist' was added in the 2002 update. The note in the second edition (1989) was

> Now differing from damp in having no tendency to imply either an undesirable or a merely temporary or casual condition. In early use the word had a wider application.

The three historical quotes from the 1900s given for the cited definition of 'moist' are from a US author (1901), an Australian author (1972), and the *Toronto Star* (Canadian, 1993). These quotes have no explicit bearing on the aforementioned observation concerning the "lesser degree of wetness" connoted by 'moist'.

Comment: +1 this matches how I've always understood it - "moist" being just damp enough to be noticeable to touch, "damp" being sufficiently moist to moisten other things that come in contact with it, contaminating them with dampness.

Answer (score 4):

The word "moist" has a visceral effect that is not shared with "damp". 
Moist and damp object have, as noted in dictionaries "slight wetness", and to this extent they are synonymous. However "moist" also has a meaning in medicine of "Marked by fluid discharge". You could describe some something in with liquid on the surface as "moist".

While the dictionaries note that dampness is unpleasant,  moistness has been called [the most hated word](http://mentalfloss.com/article/64984/science-behind-why-people-hate-word-moist), especially among younger people. This seems to be a recent development, with older people happy to describe a cake as moist, with a positive sense.  However moistness seems to have picked up sexual connotations and senses of rankness, that have made the word one to be avoided, when a relatively neutral term such as damp is available. There are words with a negative sense that dont carry the same visceral impact, such as "soggy".

As an aside, the word "rank", meaning foetid or gross, went through a similar change in meaning, changing from luxuriant, to overripe to its modern meaning. Moist may develop in the same way.

Comment: This is all interesting, but does it answer the question? Unlike forums, this is a question and answer site. the entire post can be deleted as "not an answer." Please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: Edited to focus on the question.

Comment: I'll happily disagree with the idea that "moist" has a greater visceral effect. Probably it's more prominent because of its (still largely positive) association with the body, and so it gets more focus. But if one were to survey the public with the question "would you rather be damp or moist", I doubt "damp" would win. In any event "damp" seems more applicable to a diaper, or to clothes that one would prefer to change. Further, I know people who would gag at the thought of "soggy" anything, e.g. sandwiches, pizza crust, etc. Apply it to the body and you're finished!

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary definitions and other literary analyses aside, my personal connotative impression finds **damp** as just slightly wetter than **moist**.

Specifically, a **damp** washcloth will tend to leave a small puddle behind when picked up, and probably drip as well; a **moist** washcloth will do neither, but the moisture can still be felt by touch. Add a little more water to the **moist** washcloth and it will become **damp**.

Comment: My personal connotations are the opposite

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford English Dictionary has as one of its definitions for **damp**

> To make moist or humid, to wet as steam, vapour, mist, or dew does; to moisten.

The Oxford English Dictionary also has as one of its definitions of **moist** as:

> Of a season, climate, etc.: Wet; rainy; having some rain; having a considerable rainfall.

So perhaps **moist** is wetter as *having a considerable rainfall* is much wetter than *mist or dew*

And further more, it defines *moisten* (which **damp** is defined as doing) as:

> To make or render moist, damp, or wet; to wet superficially or moderately

So that seems to prove **damp** is only wet *superficially or moderately* where as **moist** can be much more so.

Comment: Your willingness to edit is impressive, :) Welcome!

Comment: +1. I think this is the only relevant answer so far.

Comment: Can't edit out only two apostrophes, but it's means it is, whereas its means belonging to it. Common misconception!

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the heads up! Edited accordingly. :)

Comment: @PaulEvans - Please stick around. Seriously! (I used to - probably still do - always write *it's* for *its*. It's only after many months of corrections here that its grip on me has come undone.)

Comment: @medica Cheers mate - it's(!) great to be mentored! :)))) OED Mentor: The name of the Ithacan noble whose disguise the goddess Athene assumed in order to act as the guide and adviser of the young Telemachus.

Comment: @PaulEvans - I did not know that! Very, very cool to learn something new, and to find another who enjoys Greek mythology.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the degree of wetness is the same for damp and moist: appropriate to cause the word's use. In my experience, fathering two girls, I used damp to describe a moist diaper and wet to describe a much soggier one. When wiping the kitchen counter with a damp cloth, I had to first moisten it. I know the technical answer has been given, and I don't disagree with it; but usage develops our choice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, though their definitions do not make clear a difference in degree, damp notes unpleasantness, which, more often that not, would have more liquid that a pleasant amount. The words themselves, however, do not differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this question denotatively, the words both define to (more or less) "slightly wet".

Given this we must then determine the question to be answered connotatively. When we look at the usage of the action to dampen and the usage of the action to moisten, then often times dampening something (such as a towel) would require more water than to moisten something (such as the mouth).

However, given that this is more of a gray area question, it is much more likely the professor was looking for a stance and defense to show critical thinking than an ultimatum.

Answer (score -2):

The answer from fard covers all formal aspects for the answer. It also supports my thoughts:

I would use **damp** in contexts describing solid matter. eg a towel, whereas I would use **moist** in contexts describing gaseous matter. e.g. air.

With that, from a Physics's point of view I would say **damp** is more wet.

Comment: The problem with opinion is that that's all it is. In the US, one can buy moist towelettes anywhere. Moist cake is better than dry. A damp basement is the pits. The exceptions to your examples are very numerous.

Comment: @medica The question is: wich one is more wet. So your comment supports my point of view.

Comment: You stated damp for solids (a towel) and moist for air. How did my two solid *moists* and a damp *airspace* support your point of view? They do not.  It's all still only your opinion, and now your misinterpretation of my comment.